# Страничка в локальной сети из вне

Tags: apache

Ни как не могу разобраться с входом на странику с внешнх ip адресов...

**В наличии**:
 - Роутер тплинк
 - 5 Пк подцепленных к роутеру (ос виндовс)
 - Витая пара в роутер корпаративной сети
 - ОпенСервер 5.2.2 (OS)

**Что я делаю**: 
В роутер входит витая пара с сетью корпорации на выходе 5 проводов к каждому ПК в кабинете(имеют постоянные ip 192.168.0.xxx). На одном из пк в этом кабинете установлен openserver со страничкой-визиткой. Страницу эту видят все кто подцепляется к роутеру по wifi и напрямую витой парой к пк(входит спокойно как по ип 192.168.0.111 так и по днс указаному в OpenServer), но Пк в этом же кабинете соединенные кабелем напрямую от корпаративной сети и имеющие нормальные ип адреса сети 172.22.xx.xxx ни как не могут посетить мою страничку ни по днс ни истественно по ип 192.168.0.111.

Подскажите пожалуйста куда копать, что где еще нужно настроить, чтобы работала страничка как от пк до роутера так и на всех остальные пк в сети подключерые к сети на прямую(внешние - корпаративные).

Comment: Если нужен доступ из-вне, тогда стоит выложить "странички" на внешний хостинг. Пустить в локалку технически можно, но это огромная дыра в безопасности.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы зайти на сайт, который работает в локальной сети, надо прописать перенаправление в роутере.

- Даём произвольное имя правилу; Открываем НЕстандартный порт на         роутере, который не занят (поле Public Port);
- Указываем IP-адрес целевого компьютера в сети, куда должен попадать
  удалённый пользователь (поле IP-Address);
- Указываем номер порта, через который работает приложение или служба на    компьютере.

Comment: Спасибо. Работает. Я кстати так же и делал, только пытался вписать 80 порт на что роутер ругался. Сегодня использовал другой  порт сервиса и всё заработало.